# Linked views in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to create a linked view in Google Chart. What a linked view is selecting a part of visualization, let's say in a pie chart, and the same is selected (or highlighted) in the linked view, which let's say is the bar chart. I am a novice at Google Charts and I don't know how to use `JavaScript` too. I picked up the code from the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) and did some modifications in it. But it does not seem to work. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        var chart2 = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

      function drawChart2() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "select" event handlers to link the two charts together, like this:

```
function drawChart() {
    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
        ['Mushrooms', 3],
        ['Onions', 1],
        ['Olives', 1],
        ['Zucchini', 1],
        ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
        title: 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
        width: 400,
        height: 300
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_1'));
    var chart2 = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_2'));

    // set up event handlers
    // when a user clicks on the PieChart, set the selection on the BarChart
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'select', function () {
        var selection = chart1.getSelection();
        for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
            // add in column information to specify selection in BarChart
            selection[i].column = 1;
        }
        chart2.setSelection(selection);
    });
    // when a user clicks on the BarChart, set the selection on the PieChart
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart2, 'select', function () {
        var selection = chart2.getSelection();
        for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
            // remove column information for selection in PieChart
            selection[i].column = null;
        }
        chart1.setSelection(selection);
    });

    chart1.draw(data, options);
    chart2.draw(data, options);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

You need two divs in your HTML, one for each chart:

```
<div id="chart_div_1"></div>
<div id="chart_div_2"></div>
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/S78sB/

Comment: Thanks for explaining how they can be kept together, but the views are not completely linked. It works when I select the view, but not when I hover my mouse. Like, if I hover my mouse over mushrooms in the pie chart, the same is not selected in the bar chart. Can something be done about it?

Comment: You can't spawn the tooltips in the other chart, but you can use "onmouseover" event handlers to set the selection in the other chart.  See http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/S78sB/3/

Comment: This is almost perfect. There is just a little problem to be ironed out. Now when I hover my mouse on one visualization the corresponding part on the other visualization is selected, but when I remove my mouse from the first visualization, that region in the second visualization still remains selected, when it's ideal that it is completely deselected. Can this be achieved?

Comment: You can use "onmouseout" event handlers to clear them.  Using the mouseover/mouseout event handlers actually obviates the need for the "select" handlers, as the other chart gets highlighted on mouseover (before a select can happen), and cleared on a mouseout (after a select has happened).  See http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/S78sB/4/

Comment: @asgallant Can I use this approach to filter data for another chart. I need to create a pie chart and a bar chart. Clicking on the one of the pies should filter corresponding data on the bar chart and similarly, clicking on the one of the bars of the bar chart filters out data for the pie.

Comment: @NishantKumar yes, this technique should work with filtering data. It's been a while since I last used the Visualization API, but if I recall correctly, you should be able to create a `DataView` populated with rows filtered from the underlying `DataTable` (using the [`getFilteredRows` method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getFilteredRows)), and redraw the appropriate chart with the `DataView` instead of the `DataTable`. [continued...]

Comment: [...continued] There are a couple of common issues you should be aware of that other developers encountered frequently when attempting this type of cross filtering. Take care to avoid circular filtering when the user selects something in both charts and gets stuck, unable to return to an unfiltered state. There is also a possibility of infinite loops if you preserve selection in one chart when the user selects something in the other (select chart A filters chart B, selecting in chart B filters chart A, preserving the selection in A throws the "select" event, which filters chart B, repeat).

Comment: Yes...encountered that problem. For now driving filters from one chart to another and not backwards.